# Gulp.js task, return on src?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm new to gulp and have been looking through example set-ups.
Some people have the following structure:

```
gulp.task("XXXX", function() {
    gulp.src("....
```

Other people have this:

```
gulp.task("XXXX", function() {
   return gulp.src("....
```

I'm wondering what difference the **return** on the src makes??

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You `return` to indicate that the task is async. `gulp.src()` returns a stream, so it's async.

Without it the task system wouldn't know when it finished. Read the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).

Comment: Does that mean, that you *must* return when using `gulp.src()`?
What happens if you don't return  `gulp.src()`?

Comment: I second @jbandi's - the obvious question to ask here is "is there ever any reason not to return `gulp.src(...`, or should we do it always?" This answer would be more useful if it addressed that point, IMO; at present it doesn't address why there are many examples out there of tasks that call `gulp.src(...` but don't return it.

Comment: @SindreSorhus: You just solved a problem I've been trying to solve for at least 2 hours. Thanks!

Comment: @jbandi: If you don't ```return``` then the dependency system might start the a task before its dependencies are done. I've got a gulpfile with a lot of tasks (mostly code-generated). Because I wasn't returning the stream, a dependent task was already reading the file while its dependency was still building. Got me in all sorts of trouble...

Comment: So what do you return when you don't want to continue with the task, i.e. some validation failed? When I just use "return" I get "The following tasks did not complete: <task-name>". EDIT: found it, I'll post for anyone who needs it: you need to call the callback method that is passed to the task as parameter. For example add the parameter "done" to the task, and then call "return done();".

Answer (score 37):

If you have dependent tasks you need to **return** the stream for the tasks to wait on their dependent tasks to complete before running themselves.

**eg**

```
// without return
gulp.task('task1', function() {
    gulp.src('src/coffee/*.coffee')
      /* eg compile coffeescript here */
     .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});

gulp.task('task2', ['task1'], function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.js')
      /* eg minfify js here */
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

in that example you'd expect **task1** to complete ( eg compiling the coffeescript or whatever ) before **task2** runs ... but unless we add **return** – like the example below – then they will run synchronously not asynchronously; and the compiled coffeescript will not be minified because **task2** will not have waited for task 1 to complete and so will not pick up on the compiled output of **task1**. So we should always return in these circumstances.

```
// with return
gulp.task('task1', function() {
    return gulp.src('**/*.coffee')
      /* your operations here */
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});

gulp.task('task2', ['task1'], function() {
    return gulp.src('**/*.js')
      /* your operations here */
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

**Edit:** The recipe here explains it further. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Answer (score 26):

I found this helpful, if you have multiple streams per task. You need to combine/merge the multiple streams and return them.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var merge = require('gulp-merge');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    var bootstrap = gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/bootstrap'));

    var jquery = gulp.src('jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/jquery'));

    return merge(bootstrap, jquery);
});
```

The alternative, using Gulps task definition structure, would be:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('bootstrap', function() {
    return gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/bootstrap'));
});

gulp.task('jquery', function() {
    return gulp.src('jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/jquery'));
});

gulp.task('test', ['bootstrap', 'jquery']);
```