# gulp performing task multiple times

Tags: gulp

I have the following code fragment in my gulpfile.

```js
gulp.task('static', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./src/**', '!./src/js/**', '!./src/js/', '!./src/scss/', '!./src/scss/**'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + '/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['./src/**', '!./src/js/**', '!./src/js/', '!./src/scss/', '!./src/scss/**'], ['static']);
});

gulp.task('dev', ['static']);

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'dev']);
```

If I run `gulp dev`, `gulp watch` or `gulp static`, everything works fine. However, if I run just `gulp` (default), it does the `static` task **5** times. Can anyone help me out with why this is happening?

P.S. The paths passed to watch are such because if I don't disclude the directories as separate paths, it seems to be copying the empty directories `js` and `scss` for some reason.

Comment: What is the value of `outputDir` ?

Comment: It is set to either `build/` or `deploy/`, based on whether the task called was development or production.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're not returning the tasks, and you need them to be asyc.

See this: [Gulp.js task, return on src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699146/gulp-js-task-return-on-src)

and the docs (also linked in SO post above) https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support

Also, the `dev` task looks redundant in its current form - you may as well use the task `static` directly, unless you plan to bundle in more tasks with `dev`

Comment: I removed a large part of the code in the example up there. `dev` has several dependencies. There's also a typo, the `static` task does have a return.

Comment: Does `watch` need to return too?