# is it mandatory to return gulp.src()?

Tags: gulp

I am confused about `gulp.src()`.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699146/gulp-js-task-return-on-src) I would assume that it is necessary to **return** `gulp.src()`.

The examples on the gulp project always return `gulp.src()`. i.e. the [gulp intro sample](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/).

However many plugins do show documentation that do not return `gulp.src()`. i.e: [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) or [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache)

How should I decide if my task should return gulp.src()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always return `gulp.src` so that gulp can properly sink the stream for you. The stream may not complete otherwise, if you have a large number of files in it. Plus you get some other (minor) benefits such as that the correct task completion time will be logged by the runner.

Oftentimes I'll see people praising gulp for tasks that are reported as taking microseconds to complete, but all they did was not return the stream. The task took just as long to complete if we had returned the stream, however.

The other problem with not returning the stream is setting up dependent tasks. If you want some task to run before another task, you need to tell gulp that you're done processing. You either do this with a callback function for the task, or by returning the stream.

The only case in which I would not return the stream is if I have more than one stream in a single task; for that you can use [merge-stream](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream):

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('task', function () {
    var someOperation = gulp.src('./').pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
    var someOtherOperation = gulp.src('./assets').pipe(gulp.dest('out/assets'));

    return merge(someOperation, someOtherOperation);
});
```

So... while it is not *mandatory*, it is a best practice. I would suggest to pull request those plugin author's repositories to update their README files to indicate this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! However I have now a Gulp setup, that does not work when returning `gulp.src()` ... and I don't understand why? I would be very grateful if you could have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789367/gulp-does-not-work-when-returning-stream

Comment: I have a gulp task, where I just want to use [gulp-shell](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell). So in this case I just take a random input file as a src to run it once? Can I take the `gulpfile.js` itself to make sure that this file exists? E.g.: `return gulp.src('gulpfile.js', { read: false }).pipe(shell(['yarn list global']))`
Thanks for some input on this...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not return the stream, gulp will report the time it takes to build the pipe. If you return the stream, it will correctly report the time it takes to execute the task(s).