# Gulp does not work when returning stream

Tags: gulp

The following Gulp setup does not work:

```
var templateCache = require("gulp-angular-templatecache");
var less = require("gulp-less");

gulp.task("angular-templates", function(){
      return gulp.src(TEMPLATES_SOURCES)
        .pipe(templateCache(TEMPLATES_JS, {module: "moonwalk", root: TEMPLATES_ROOT}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("Temp/"));
});

gulp.task("less-compile",function(){
      return gulp.src("**/*.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});

gulp.task("release-assets", ["angular-templates", "less-compile"], function() {

    return gulp.src("./Content/**/*.cshtml")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("Dist/"));
});
```

When I run `gulp release-assets` the output is the following:

```
[01:24:06] Starting 'angular-templates'...
[01:24:06] Starting 'less-compile'...
[01:24:06] Finished 'angular-templates' after 605 ms
```

... not good ...

However if I change the second task by removing the `return` like this:

```
gulp.task("less-compile",function(){
       gulp.src("**/*.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
});
```

Then the setup does work!? The output of `gulp release-assets` then is:

```
[01:21:54] Starting 'angular-templates'...
[01:21:54] Starting 'less-compile'...
[01:21:54] Finished 'less-compile' after 2.89 ms
[01:21:54] Finished 'angular-templates' after 741 ms
[01:21:54] Starting 'release-assets'...
[01:22:03] Finished 'release-assets' after 8.9 s
```

I do not understand that problem. I thought it was mandatory to `return` the stream that is provided by `gulp.src()`?

Can somebody explain, why the above setup is not working if I return on `gulp.src()`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where the problem is here, but I don't believe that it is your use (or non-use) of `return`. To be honest I'm having a little difficulty understanding how this all works, but it appears at a casual glance that you are writing files into temporary directories and reading them later. Don't do this! Instead you should look at tools like merge-stream that will let you control flow, so that you can perform all of these operations in memory.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the tip of not writing temporary files. But I think that is not the issue here. I simplified the setup and updated the question: The problem still remains, even when the last task does not do anything at all. I suspect it has something to do with declaring the dependency to two other tasks?

Comment: Are you using [gulp-less](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-less)?

Comment: @Ben Yes, I am using [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) in the second task.

Comment: What version of [gulp-less](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-less)? Also, do all of your less files get compiled as expected in the second scenario?

Comment: @Ben "gulp-less": "2.0.1", Right now I have just one less file in the project. That file gets compiled as expected with the second scenario.

Comment: This looks all OK to me. But I wonder if the glob you have there is a bit far-reaching; if you could try organising your less source files into some directory (maybe `./lib/styles`) and write them to, say, `./dist/css`. I haven't seen gulp tasks just not complete like that, but then I don't run Windows...

Comment: @Ben (Un)fortunately it shows exactly the same behavior on my Mac.

Comment: @Ben You are the man! Narrowing the glob solved the problem! With `gulp-debug` I have now seen that with the wide glob also a lot of less files from `node_modules` attempted to be processed ... still I find it strange that this lead to the observed behavior (no error message at all).

Comment: @Ben If you formulate it as an answer, I will accept it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main points raised in the comments; `return` doesn't seem like it is throwing off gulp; you are using the latest version of gulp-less, and your tasks look OK from a syntax standpoint.

The main takeaway from this is that project structure is quite important, so that when you specify a glob such as `**/*.less` you have to be aware of what files it can match; in this case the glob is far too greedy and will match things in `node_modules` that may or may not be relevant to your project. Because `gulp.src` is an expensive operation, it is a good practice to organise your source files into directories and limit `glob`'s scope to be within those directories.

A better glob pattern would be something along the lines of `./lib/styles/**/*.less` - that way you have both scoped the glob appropriately and you also keep your less files in one place. Your gulp task should therefore look something like the following:

```
gulp.task("less-compile", function () {
    return gulp.src("./lib/styles/**/*.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by changing the installed gulp version from  3.8.7 to 3.8.5 in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.5"
  }
```

Must be a change or error in the newer version preventing the pipe(gulp.src('*.*')) from resolving the return statement.