# Gulp.js - Not able to copy generated files from one folder to another

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {

   gulp.src(['src/test/test.css])
   .pipe(concat('test1.css'))
   .pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/source/'))
   .pipe(filesize())

});
gulp.task('copy-css',['minify-css'], function () {

   gulp.src('src/source/*.css')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/dest/'));

});
```

It seems that the first time I run 'gulp copy-css'

```
Starting 'minify-css'...
[18:54:39] Finished 'minify-css' after 61 ms
[18:54:39] Starting 'copy-css'...
[18:54:39] Finished 'copy-css' after 1.86 ms
```

but the copy operation doesn't execute probably because it executes even before the file to be copied is not generated

Even though I have mentioned minify-css as dependency for copy-css task, it seems it is not following that convention in this case.

When gulp copy-css is run another time, this time the file is copied because the file is already generated from previously executed command. But this would beat the purpose when the code is being used in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change both the tasks as below

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    return  gulp.src(['src/test/test.css])
   .pipe(concat('test1.css'))
   .pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/source/'))
   .pipe(filesize())    
});

gulp.task('copy-css',['minify-css'], function () {
   return gulp.src('src/source/*.css')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/dest/'));

});
```

add return so that next task runs after first one runs, else your copy-csss is running even before minify-css is finished.. hence the error...

Comment: Well, it is a good solution for this situation. But if add another file to be minified in 'minify-css' task. It would not work as it would return even before minifying the next file. Any solution for that ?

Comment: no... put all your css to minify in gulp.src.. and it would work as you exepct

Comment: What i mean was, that if needed to minify another set of css files

Comment: lets say you have another task to minify another set of css files, then you would have copy-css depend on both those tasks... that would do it

Answer (score 1):

I would check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699146/gulp-js-task-return-on-src), as it seems you might have to add `return` keyword before `gulp.src(['src/test/test.css])`...

Answer (score 1):

Try with a callback in the `on('finish')` event:

```
gulp.task('minify-css', function (cb) {

   gulp.src(['src/test/test.css'])
    .pipe(concat('test1.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/source/'))
    .pipe(filesize())
    .on('finish', function() {
        // All tasks should now be done
        return cb();
    })

});

gulp.task('copy-css',['minify-css'], function () {

   gulp.src('src/source/*.css')
     .pipe(gulp.dest('src/dest/'));

});
```

PS:
You also go an syntax error in your gulp.src array at the very top, just a missing quote `'` here `gulp.src(['src/test/test.css])`