# Update: Errors with postCSS and Babel in Gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, postcss

## Goal

I'm updating my old `gulpfile.js`, which used to be mainly for compiling my Sass into CSS, but now I'm trying to get Gulp to do the following:

1. Sync browser, whip up localhost server - **DONE**
2. Compile Sass => CSS  - **DONE**
3. Show any JavaScript errors with JSHint - **DONE**

   - Compile ES6 => ES6 with Babel `(WORKING ON)`
4. Minify all assets `(WORKING ON)`

   - Show project file size - **DONE**
5. Deploy index.html, style.css and images to S3 `(WORKING ON)`
6. Watch files, reload browser when `.scss` or `.html` changes  - **DONE**

## Problem

- Trying to minify my Javascript and also create a `scripts.min.js`
  file, it keeps adding the suffix min to every new minified JavaScript
  file.

### Folder structure

```
index.html
gulpfile.js
package.json
.aws.json
.csscomb.json
.gitignore

assets
- css
style.css
style.scss

--partials
---base
---components
---modules

- img
- js
scripts.js

- dist
```

### gulpfile.js

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require("gulp-postcss");

// All of your plugins
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var csswring = require("csswring");
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var lost = require("lost");
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var rucksack = require("rucksack-css");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Sync browser, whip up server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: "./"
    }
  });
});

// Reload page automagically
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

// Compile Sass into CSS, apply postprocessors
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  var processors = [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']}),
      csswring,
      lost,
      rucksack
  ];

  gulp.src(['assets/css/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    // .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
    // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

// Show any JavaScript errors
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src('assets/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    // .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    // .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

// Minify assets, create build folder
gulp.task('images', function(){
  gulp.src('assets/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img'));
});

// Minify HTML


// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
  gulp.watch("assets/css/**/*.scss", ['styles']);
  gulp.watch("assets/js/**/*.js", ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch("*.html", ['bs-reload']);
  gulp.start("images", "styles", "scripts")
});

// var babel = require('gulp-babel');
// var minifyhtml = require("gulp-minify-html");
// var size = require("gulp-size");
// var upload = require("gulp-s3");
```

Comment: In minify task you have 2 returns for one function, separate imagemin to another task.

Comment: Also you should use return in your styles task before gulp.src http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699146/gulp-js-task-return-on-src

Answer (score 1):

Hi i can't solve all your problems but I had also a similar issue with the babel and ES6 fat arrow functions (using babelify and browserify). To solve the problem try to pass:

```
stage: 0
```

to your babel.js gulp plugin. If error will still occurs then try to pass also:

```
experimental: true
```

For more information please have a look "experimental" section on babel.js site.