# gulp.watch() not working with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

Suddenly, my gulpfile.js's watch statement for all of my jade files stopped working. Do you know why?

Jade task:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  gulp.src('app/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
      this.emit('end')
    })
    .pipe(minifyHTML())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})
```

I also use BrowserSync, so I put all my watch statements in the `serve` task, which looks like this:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['styles', 'html', 'jade', 'scripts'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './dist'
  })
  gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.sass', ['styles'])
  gulp.watch('app/*.jade').on('change', function() {
    gulp.run(['jade'])
    browserSync.reload()
  })
  gulp.watch('app/src/*.js', ['scripts'])
})
```

Also, every other watch statement works, so I really have no idea what's happening. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would try two things. 
1. add `return` in front of `gulp.src('app/*.jade')` 
2. change your `gulp.watch` for `jade` to `gulp.watch('app/*.jade', ['jade']).on('change', browserSync.reload())`. And I would recommend to upgrade from `jade` to `pug`.

Comment: Im very happy that it helped you. I wrote my answer below. Let me know which thing helped you or did you need to change both things?

Comment: I modified both things, and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two things.

1. Add `return` in front of `gulp.src('app/*.jade')` so the pipeline know it is finished (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699146/gulp-js-task-return-on-src) for more info on this)
2. Change your `gulp.watch` for `jade` to `gulp.watch('app/*.jade', ['jade']).on('change', browserSync.reload())`. Your way seems strange to me.

And I would recommend you to upgrade from jade to pug.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem, you really helped me out with adding  `return`  in front of `gulp.src('app/*.jade')`

Answer (score -1):

If there has been no code change but it suddenly stopped working there are a few things I would check.

If you are using node and npm:

- Do you have you dependencies locked in your package.json?
- Did Jade, Gulp, or browserSync update?
- When was the last time to deleted all your node_modules folder and ran an `npm install`.
- Have you switched Node versions?

Comment: I have devDependencies in my package.json, with every gulp dependency I use. No, I didn't update any of them recently,  I deleted the node_modules folder and ran npm install just today and no, I haven't swithced versions... Any other ideas?